# Flight delay time

Tags: missed-flights

Flight TOM137 flying from Dalaman airport 16/05/2019
This flight was originally due out from Dalaman airport at 01.30....but actually left at 5am 
It was a  TUI Dreamliner  plane which takes an hour off the 4 and a half flight time flight

Tui  are saying that according to their logs the flight was only delayed by 2hrs 48 mins .?
How is this possible..so does not bridge the 3 hrs delay ..Anyone help on this .thanks

Comment: The delay required for compensation is based on the ARRIVAL time, not the departure time.  When did you flight arrive, and when was it scheduled to arrive?

Comment: According to the figures in your question, the flight departed 3½ hours late and made up 1 hour enroute. Thus it would arrive 2½ hour late, which is less than 3 hours.

Comment: Also, you seem to have an issue with the flight number, TOM137 is not a flight from Dalaman.